# Show content by pages (Android/Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, spring, kotlin

I'm trying to write a simple web application, I have a back-end running on Spring and want to do a front-end as an Android app. So far I can get some list of the information from my server and show it as a text in my main activity. I'm using Kotlin. So what I want to do now is to parse Json I got into blocks and show them by pages. For example, I get 12 objects, I want to parse them and show 4 on the one page, so there would be 3 pages. Here's my code for my Android app so far:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root)

        val textView = TextView(this)
        textView.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "http://localhost/get"
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, url,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                textView.text = "Response is: ${response}"
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { response -> textView.text = "${response.message}" })
        queue.add(stringRequest)
        layout?.addView(textView)
    }
}
```

Also in the future I want to add bottom navigation bar, where you can swap between your profile (or authorization), main page and e.t.c. If someone knows any good guides on how to build app like this I would appreciate it, because I didn't find something like this, on the official Android page there's too many deprecicated layouts, libraries, but it doesn't even have any example pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Follow step by step building bottom navigation with view from [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/).

Comment: So, you are looking for some network involvement with parsing json. Please check https://androidboss.info/2017/05/25/android-bottom-navigation-activity-with-recyclerview-data-populated-by-retrofit2-and-load-images-by-glide/, its in java but java to kotlin converter can help you on this.

Comment: I already did json parsing, now I need more something like Paging library